# Printing the priority of the main

Tags: c, process, pthreads, thread-priority

I'm wondering if there is a way to print the priority of the main. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898977/printing-the-default-threads-priority/62899610#62899610) question I asked how to print the deafult priority of a thread; now I'm very curious to know if it's possible to do the same for the main.

---

EDIT: my goal is to get the priority of the unique process I created (I'm using pthread library to create threads inside the int main block). The process should not be a normal process, but a real time process, so i cannot use the getpriority function. It can be used only for normal processes (source: pag. 183, Robert Love - Linux system programming - Talking directly to the kernel and C library (2013, O'Reilly Media) 2nd Ed).

How can I get the priority of the real time process and print it?

Comment: ech. What research did you do? Like literally the function is named `getpriority`. Take a look at [sched(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html). Or at [posix sched.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sched.h.html) documentation.

Comment: @KamilCuk have I to use this https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpriority.html ? Do I get the id with pthreat_self()?

Comment: `have I to use` I have no idea _why_ do you want to do what you want, so I cannot answer what you have to use. `pthread_self()` returns a thread id. The documentation states: `The which argument may be one of the following values: PRIO_PROCESS, PRIO_PGRP, or PRIO_USER, indicating that the who argument is to be interpreted as a process ID, a process group ID, or an effective user ID`. `getpid()` returns process id.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm learning how to use the pthread library so I'm quite clumsy. When I call the getpriority the first argument should be PRIO_PROCESS because the main is the main process? And if I call getpriority in the main, the second argument should be zero?

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried the above calling of getpriority, but the result is: error: ‘PRIO_PROCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: So did you include the relevant header file? It's on top of a the man page. Type `man getpriority` to view it.

Comment: @KamilCuk ok now it works, I included sys/resource.h (the sched.h is not sufficient)...I hope that the right first argument is PRIO_PROCESS.

Comment: "*the main is the main process*". No. By "main" here, you mean the thread that's created first. The process is the container that contains an address space, file descriptors, and all the threads.

Comment: Hi @DavidSchwartz so with getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0) I'm not getting the priority of the int main, but the priority of the first thread I created? If yes, I can't get the priority of the int main with getpriority

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi No, you are getting the priority of the process, that is, the container in which all the threads live. This might be the default priority that threads created in that process get, or it might not be.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have a doubt: what is the name of the process which contains the threads? To see the code I wrote, click on the link in the question please

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Processes don't really have names. Sometimes they're named by the name of the executable. The process is the container that consists of the address space, the file descriptors, and all the threads. All the threads are part of the same process. The process owns the memory, file descriptors, and other things the threads all share. On some operating systems, processes have priorities. On some, newly-created threads start out with the priority of the thread that created them with the first created thread getting the process' priority.

Comment: thank you very very much for your explanation @DavidSchwartz

Comment: `How can I get the priority of the real time process and print it?` is a separate question, you should open a separate question for that. `sched_getparam` (and `SCHED_RR` on linux have also `sched_rr_get_interval`)

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk . The sched_rr_get_interval provides the the round-robin time quantum; how is it related to the process' priority?

Comment: `round-robin time quantum` round-robin? Why round-robin? Do you understand what the term "real-time" in computing means? A "real-time" thing is a thing with a _hard_ limit. In terms of processes, that's a time limit the process is allowed to execute.

Comment: @KamilCuk https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_rr_get_interval.2.html

Comment: So I guess that linux implementation uses round-robin. If you delve that much, see into scheduler implementation - how is priority related to time constrain, scheduler handles that.

Comment: i'm going to open a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to print the priority of the main

`getpriority` can be used to query the niceness level of a process.

`shed_getparam` can be used to query the scheduling priority of a process.

`pthread_getschedparam` can be used to query scheduling priority of a thread.

> How can I get the priority of the real time process and print it?

A real time process is typically understood as a process running with `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR` scheduling policy.

You can use the same functions as above.

> so i cannot use the getpriority function. It can be used only for normal processes

You can use `getpriority` on any process. (I think niceness level is just ignored in case of real-time scheduling, and this could be meant).